# Shape must have rank 2 but it is rank 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to make a chatbot using tensorflow in python. But I am getting this error when I am training the dataset.

**raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'model_with_buckets/sequence_
loss/sequence_loss_by_example/sampled_softmax_loss/LogUniformCandidateSampler' (
op: 'LogUniformCandidateSampler') with input shapes: [?].**

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please post exact code snippet? The parameter should be a matrix of shape [n,m] but seems like you are giving an array(or None) as a parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was getting similar error when i tried to run tensorflow "seq2seq tutorial code" compatible with the older version on tensorflow 1.0, it mainly due to change in the order of arguments to a function(**tf.nn.sampled_softmax**). It is expecting **inputs(rank 2)** but you are passing l**abels(rank 1)** So change the order of arguments according to definition of the function.

**In tf 0.12.0:**
Definition : tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights, biases, **inputs, labels,** num_sampled, num_classes, num_true=1, sampled_values=None, remove_accidental_hits=True, partition_strategy="mod", name="sampled_softmax_loss")

**In tf 1.0:**
tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights, biases, **labels, inputs,** num_sampled, num_classes, num_true=1, sampled_values=None, remove_accidental_hits=True, partition_strategy='mod', name='sampled_softmax_loss')

Comment: Ya i am running tensorflow 1.0 and now  get it why I am getting this error but I am not able to remove the error as all the inbuilt libraries used by tensorflow is being used here.

Comment: It worked by changing the order of arguments. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

````
labels_one_hot = tf.reshape(labels_one_hot, (-1, params['n_classes']))```
````